# Problems with importing dataset from scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I try to run the attached code and the attached error pops up.
I try to run the code through pycharm and scikit learn and tensorflow are
[installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPtJq.png).

I tried to perform `python setup.py install` as the comment suggests, in the path of

C: \ Users \ nirkov \ AppData \ Roaming \ Python \ Python36 \ site-packages \ sklearn \ __ check_build

And that did not solve the problem. Am I wrong where I execute the command?

Does anyone know what the problem might be?
(I was looking for this problem on the web, but unfortunately I could not fix the problem)

the code -

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing

housing = fetch_california_housing()
m, n = housing.data.shape
housing_data_plus_bias =  np.c_[np.ones((m,1)),housing.data]

X = tf.constant(housing_data_plus_bias, dtype=tf.float32, name="X")
Y = tf.constant(housing.target.reshape(-1,1), dtype=tf.float32, name="Y")
X_Transpose = tf.transpose(X)
theta = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(tf.matrix_inverse(tf.matmul(X_Transpose, X)), X_Transpose), y)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    theta_value = theta.eval()
```

the error -

```
"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" "D:/Python Projects/learningTensorFlow/LinearRegressionWithTensorFlow.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nirkov\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from ._check_build import check_build  # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python Projects/learningTensorFlow/LinearRegressionWithTensorFlow.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
  File "C:\Users\nirkov\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from . import __check_build
  File "C:\Users\nirkov\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build\__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    raise_build_error(e)
  File "C:\Users\nirkov\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build\__init__.py", line 41, in raise_build_error
    %s""" % (e, local_dir, ''.join(dir_content).strip(), msg))
ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of C:\Users\nirkov\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build:
setup.py                  _check_build.cp36-win32.pyd__init__.py
__pycache__
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.
```

Comment: Do you pip? try pip install sklearn

Comment: I installed the libraries through pip

Comment: Are you using Anaconda? He has a lof libraries, I supposted that's help.